# UIScrollView scrollbar width and height?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, scrollbar

Is there a way to reference the width and height of the scrollbars in a UIScrollView? I see content size and content offset, but neither seems like it will help.

TL;DR
To keep track of the lowest Y position of the views I’ve added to a `UIScrollView`, I use:

```
lowestView = scrollView.subviews.sorted(by: { $0.frame.maxY < $1.frame.maxY }).last?.frame.maxY ?? 0
```

But this doesn’t take into account the fact that a `UIScrollView` already includes two subviews for the scrollbars - which, of course, messes up the above calculation.

What I’d really like to do is filter the scrollbars from the subview. Which would look something like:

```
let goodViews = scrollView.subviews.filter( {$0.frame.height > 7 && $0.frame.width > 7} )
```

Except I know that hard coding those values will get me in trouble someday, which is why I’d like the reference instead. Thanks!

Comment: Probably not a good idea to try and "filter out" the scroll indicators... things can change over time. Better bet is to add your subviews to an array at the same time you add them to the scroll view, then use `lowestView = myArrayOfSubviews.sorted(...)`

Comment: That’s a good point. I started with an array but it seemed like one more thing to keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is *an* option:

```
let bv = scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator
let bh = scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

let lowestView = scrollView.subviews.sorted(by: { $0.frame.maxY < $1.frame.maxY }).last?.frame.maxY ?? 0

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = bv
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = bh
```

I only did a quick test, but seems reliable.